# expect: Parse variables from stdin

Tags: linux, bash, expect

I am running an `expect` script that will generate some dynamic input coming from `stdin`.

Is there a way/pattern that addresses the concept of reading from the stdin and storing (?) somewhere the relevant input to be processed/parsed in a latter step?

**example**:

```
./myexpectscript.sh arg1 arg2 ..

Running command with id 9494
Running command with id 9494
Running command with id 9494
Running command with id 9494
Command execution finished
```

I actually want to store the above id,`9494`.

The script actually runs an api call to a remote server and has a duration of several seconds (for what that matters).

**edit**: the following snippet does not seem to resolve the issue:

```
expect -re Running command with id [0-9]+

set output \$expect_out(1,string)
```

as it gives me an error:

```
invalid command name "0-9"
    while executing
"0-9"
    invoked from within
"expect -re Running command with id [0-9]+"
    (file "./myexpectscript.sh" line 17)
```

have also tried it with quotes, i.e.

```
expect -re "Running command with id [0-9]+"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `{...}` to define your regex, use `\d` for decimal number, and capture the string with `(...)`.

Set a variable with the captured string with `$expect_out`.

```
expect -re {Running command with id (\d+)} {
    set cmd_id $expect_out(1,string)
}
puts $cmd_id
```

Comment: many thanks... this seems to be doing the job ...is there a way to store somewhere the variable __outside__ the script? the following: `VAR=$(./myexpectscript.sh arg1 arg2)` did not work.

Comment: if you use `puts` in the expect script, you should be able to get the string when doing `$(./myexpectscript ... )`. Do you get any error, or an empty string?

Comment: I have managed to address this by disabling all other output `log_user 0` and making use of `puts`, yes.